# Use drawer combine with self-built list tile menu

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I successfully achieve the sidebar menu by using drawer and ListTile, but the problem is when the ListTile tapped and the drawer closed, I reopen the drawer will see that the tapped ListTile will be reset to untapped color. How to solve this problem? I try so many time but I can't figure the solution out.

menu_list dart file

```
class MenuList extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(int, String) onTap;

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> menu = [];
  MenuList({required this.onTap, required this.menu});

  @override
  State<MenuList> createState() => _MenuListState();
}

class _MenuListState extends State<MenuList> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  Widget buildListTile(Map<String, dynamic> item, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        item["title"],
        style: TextStyle(
            color: _selectedIndex == index ? Colors.deepOrangeAccent : Colors.grey,
        ),
      ),
      leading: Icon(
        item['leading'],
        color: _selectedIndex == index ? Colors.deepOrangeAccent : Colors.grey,
      ),
      tileColor: Colors.white,
      onTap: (){
        setState(() {
          _selectedIndex = index;
        });
        widget.onTap(index, item['title']);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: widget.menu.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return buildListTile(widget.menu[index], index);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

mDashboard dart file

```
class MobileDashboard extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<MobileDashboard> createState() => _MobileDashboardState();
}

class _MobileDashboardState extends State<MobileDashboard> {

  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final PageController _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  String _selectedTitle = '';
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> menu = [
    {'title': 'Playlists', 'leading':Icons.featured_play_list},
    {'title': 'Menu..', 'leading':Icons.send},
    {'title': 'Logout', 'leading':Icons.logout},
  ];

  void handleTap(int index, String title) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedTitle = title;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _selectedTitle = 'Playlists';
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      endDrawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 100,
                  child: DrawerHeader(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: IconButton(
                                onPressed: (){
                                  Get.back(result: false);
                                },
                                icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.xmark)
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Icon(Icons.info_outline, size: 24, color: Colors.grey,),
                        SizedBox(width: 27.3,),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 28,
                          height: 28,
                          child: CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/loginBG.png'),),
                        ),

                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: MenuList(
                      onTap: handleTap,
                      menu: menu),
                )
              ]
          )
      ),
```

Comment: can you make `MobileDashboard` minimal,(only necessary part that will be needed to reproduce the same error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the initial index on `MenuList`.

```dart
class MenuList extends StatefulWidget {
  const MenuList({
    this.initialSelectedIndex = 0,
    required this.onTap,
    required this.menu,
  });
  final Function(int, String) onTap;
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> menu;
  final int initialSelectedIndex;

  @override
  State<MenuList> createState() => _MenuListState();
}

class _MenuListState extends State<MenuList> {
  late int _selectedIndex = widget.initialSelectedIndex;

  Widget buildListTile(Map<String, dynamic> item, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        item["title"],
        style: TextStyle(
          color:
              _selectedIndex == index ? Colors.deepOrangeAccent : Colors.grey,
        ),
      ),
      leading: Icon(
        item['leading'],
        color: _selectedIndex == index ? Colors.deepOrangeAccent : Colors.grey,
      ),
      tileColor: Colors.white,
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _selectedIndex = index;
        });
        widget.onTap(index, item['title']);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: widget.menu.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return buildListTile(widget.menu[index], index);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And on usecase(on state class)

```dart
  int selectedIndex = 0;

  void handleTap(int index, String title) {
    selectedIndex = index;
    setState(() {
      _selectedTitle = title;
    });
    .....code...
  }
```

inside build method

```dart
 MenuList(
  onTap: handleTap,
  menu: menu,
  initialSelectedIndex: selectedIndex,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

See the problem is, when you click on other item in your menu , it goes to other page lets say menu, Now again again page gets build and then MenuList() is called, inside MenuList() you have written int selectedindex = 0, so always it will display playlist. approach is also not a good one

Better approach is

1. Make a List of pages/Widgets you want to show like

   static final List_widgetOptions = [
   const Text("Home"),
   UserProfilePage(),
   const Text("Search"),
   const Text("Settings")
   ];

   ```
     void _onItemTapped(int index){
       setState(() {
         _selectedIndex = index;
       });
     }
   ```
2. then write drawer code when user taps on item it would get routed to widget we define in above list

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Drawer(
   child: ListView(
   children: [

   ```
           UserAccountsDrawerHeader(

             accountName: GestureDetector(
             // onTap: () => setState(() {
             //     _selectedIndex = 1;
             //   }),
             onTap: () {
               setState(() {
                 _selectedIndex = 1;
               });
               Navigator.pop(context);
             },
             child:const Text("username",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20) ,)), 
           currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
             child:  ClipOval(
               child: Image.asset('lib/images/dhruv.png.jpg',
               width:90,
               height : 90,
               fit :BoxFit.cover),



               )

           ),

           accountEmail:const Text("email")),
           ListTile(
             leading: Icon(Icons.payment),
             title: const Text("Home"),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
               setState(() {
                 _selectedIndex = 0;
               });
               Navigator.pop(context);

             },
           ),
   ```

code is different but understand the flow, we need to call pages from the drawer itself, and not like, from a page call a drawer